# Maintain index of days while recursing

Tags: java

In the following code i am trying to find which is the best day to buy and sell a stock. However i am only able to calculate the profit that i have from buying and selling at the correct days but i am not able to find the days (index) since they are lost in the recursion. I don't want to use any static variable. The only solution i am thinking is to add a new private method that will hold the correct days.

```
public class Stock {

public static int maximum(int[] half) {
    int max=half[0]; 
    int index=0;
    for (int i=1; i<half.length; i++) {
        if (half[i]>max) {
            max = half[i];
            index=i;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
public static int minimum(int[] half) {
    int min=half[0]; 
    int index=0;
    for (int i=1; i<half.length; i++) {
        if (half[i]<min) {
            min = half[i];
            index=i;
        }
    }

    return min;
}

private static int maxProfit(int[] stock) {
    if (stock.length<= 1)
        return 0;

    int left[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(stock, 0, stock.length/2);
    int right[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(stock, (stock.length/2), stock.length);

    int maxLeft = maxProfit(left);
    int maxRight = maxProfit(right);


    int bothSides = maximum(right) - minimum(left);

    return Math.max(Math.max(maxLeft,maxRight), bothSides);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] stock_t = { 13, 5, 2, 12, 3, 15 };

    int fi = maxProfit(stock_t);
    System.out.println(fi);
}
```

}

Comment: If you do not want to use a static variable, then the only other options I see are to make the methods not static and use a class variable, or as you suggest, make an additional method that contains the accumulated data

Comment: Well, if i use an additional method then it will print all the possible combination of days and the last one should ve my solution. Am i right?

Comment: It depends entirely on how that method is written.  If the method returns an `int` in the method that calls it originally it can print just the output of that.  The method calling itself does not need to trigger any print statements

Comment: There is no problem at all. The matter is what you want to do. Do you want to retain the last updated value of `days` or you want to keep the initial value of `days` before calculations?

Comment: I want to retain the last updated value of days. I tried the additional method but i dont get the desired result. I am always ending with 0 and 5 on the above result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retain the last updated value of days

You can add an instance variable to your class to retain the last updated value for days:

```
public class Stock{
    private int days;

    public int getDays(){
        return days;
    }
}
```

To retain the value for days after calculation, update the value before the method exits:

```
//In Stock class
public int maximum(int[] half) {    //Make this an instance method (remove static)
    int max=half[0]; 
    int index=0;
    for (int i=1; i<half.length; i++) {
        if (half[i]>max) {
            max = half[i];
            index=i;
        }
    }
    days = index;                   //update before method exits
    return max;
}
```

You may also update `days` in whichever place that is appropriate.

To get the value for days:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] stock_t = { 13, 5, 2, 12, 3, 15 };
    Stock s = new Stock();              //create Stock object
    int fi = s.maxProfit(stock_t);      //calculations will update days attribute
    System.out.println(s.getDays());    //get days according to last calculation
}
```

All your methods are static which seems a little weird to me in terms implementation. If your `Stock` class is supposed to act as a template for creating `Stock` objects and each individual `Stock` object retains its own state, your methods and attributes are more appropriate to be declared as `non-static`.

If your `Stock` class is to be used as an utility class for just invoking methods, then those methods can be `static`. But according to your question, this doesn't seems to be the case.